# Migrate Oracle CONNECT BY to postgresql 10

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration, recursive-query

i have this SQL:

```
SELECT count(*) as ct
          FROM classifications cls
WHERE
   cls.classification_id = :classification_id
START WITH cls.classification_id = :root_classification_id
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR cls.classification_id = cls.parent_id
```

and need to migrate it to postgresql 10.

I have already installed the extension tablefunc and tried with connectedby. here my try:

```
SELECT count(*) as ct
          FROM classifications cls
WHERE
   cls.classification_id = :classification_id

union
                  SELECT count(classification_id) FROM connectby('classifications','classification_id','parent_id',:root_classification_id,5)
                  as t(classification_id varchar, parent_id varchar,level int)
```

Problem is that the union is the wrong way because then you get 2 results of the count.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use the tablefunc extension. This can easily be done using a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
with recursive tree as (

  select cls.classification_id, cls.parent_id 
  from classifications cls
  where cls.classification_id = :root_classification_id

  union all

  select child.classification_id, child.parent_id
  from classifications child
     join tree parent on child.parent_id = parent.classification_id
)
select count(*)
from tree;
```

The first query inside the CTE matches the `start with` part from Oracle's `start with`. And the JOIN back to the CTE in the second query matches the `connect by` part in the Oracle query.

Comment: Worth noting that this works in most RDBMSs with few modifications. I wonder if ltree is a good choice too? It's an additional module but results in *far* better performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I have never worked with the ltree extension, but recursive queries are quite efficient in Postgres (I have used them with trees containing thousands of rows out of tables with millions of rows without any problems - proper indexes assumed)

Comment: Not as efficient as a single range query over an index. LTree is like SQL Server's `hierarchyid` - a binary path encoding roughly similar to `ID1\ID2` etc which means searching for children is essentially a range query similar to `like 'ID1\%`. Searching for parents, just looking for those `ID`s. Nested sets are also fast but far harder to maintain, and they need manual implementation anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: if the current structure in Oracle performed good enough, I am sure this query will be good enough in Postgres as well.